# Avg. Visit Duration 00:00:00 conclusion

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, search, visitors

What can I predict when I see in Google Analytics that total visits by search for some day are 93 visits while 70 visits of them have the value 00:00:00 for Avg. Visit Duration?

Did those visits made by robots? or How could they regarded as visits while they don't spend any time on the website? Or this is dysfunction of the Google's Analytics script by which it does not able to count the visit time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically what this means is the user only stayed long enough for GA to load then closed the browser or left the page immediately afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

As described others here, I once "solved" this issue by moving the Google Analytics script to the head where it had previously been placed in the footer.  I would assume that the page loaded the script first and then monitored the time on page.

I was seeing this issue on a site with verbose source code (sorry, I can't recall how many lines ... but a lot!).  After **I moved the code from the footer to the header**, I started seeing realistic times for a certain page.  Unfortunately, I didn't cross-check a number of pages as I was focused on one particular gateway page.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on the answer above, this can be influenced by the location (most commonly in the head or right before the closing body tag) of your snippet, and of course load time.